Access to "API Platform" connected app
Hello,
We use a gateway (Kong) between Salesforce and external systems and I have to put the consumer key of the Salesforce connected app "API Platform" in Kong to autorize connection but unfortunately, I can't see "API Platofmr" in the "App Manager" menu or the "Manage Connected Apps" menu.
I tried to find the solution on the internet but I didn't find it.
Does someone knows where is this connected app please?
Thanks

Does Kong provide the "API Platform" connected app in its managed package, or do you have to create a connected app for this?

Based on your inputs you seem to be using a connected app and there could be several reason for it be not showing. Check if your user have the Manage Connected Apps permission you can check it from your profiles system permissions.

My profile has the "Manage Connected Apps" permission checked but I still don't see this connected app.
Do you agree this connected app exists?
I remember it is a standard connected app?

No, by default Salesforce doesnt have standard ones but you can install prebuilt ones from managed packages or create connected apps to meet your requirements

I compared with another sandbox and it is in the "External Client App Manager" menu.
What is weird is this connected app was not created after the refresh of the sandbox from Production but the connected app exists in Production.
I have to create the connected app manually I think.

Based on your scenario it seems to be a Local External Client app. As per the documentation only Packaged External Client apps are copied to the sandboxes during refresh.
Documentation : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_apps_and_external_client_apps_features.htm&type=5

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

I fixed the issue.
I created an external connected app, I put the consumer key of the new app into Kong and I put the Kong certificate into the new external connected app for the JWT flow, it works well.

You can accept your own answer.
